# В IE7 фон одного блока почему-то закрасил и другой блок

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Задал зеленый цвет для блока после хедера, а в IE7 он почему то и хедер закрашивает! В IE8 не на всю ширину растягивается... Что это такое? надеюсь кто-то поможет.
Вот сайт - http://websterjoy.tk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас не закрыт `<div class='header-inside'>`. Перед закрывающим тегом `</header>` у вас открыт новый див `<div>`, вместо `</div>`